# Is there a way to send FCM push notification to all the email address i have in my local database

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, lumen, cordova-plugin-fcm

Well I'm setting up a database where user details would be stored using ionic as front end and lumen to make API calls. My concern is that can i send a push notification to all the people who are using my application using the email information that is in my database. Is it possible

Following is the code that i am trying to do :

```
public function send_notification_all(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title' => 'required|max:30|min:20',
        'message' => 'required'
        ]);

    $noti_title = $request->input('title');
    $noti_body = $request->input('message');

    $optionBuilder = new OptionsBuilder();
    $optionBuilder->setTimeToLive(60*20);

    $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder($noti_title);
    $notificationBuilder->setBody($noti_body)
                        ->setSound('default');

    $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
    $dataBuilder->addData(['a_data' => 'my_data']);

    $option = $optionBuilder->build();
    $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
    $data = $dataBuilder->build();
    $email = User::pluck('email')->toArray();
    $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($email, $option, $notification, $data);

    $downstreamResponse->numberSuccess();
    $downstreamResponse->numberFailure();
    $downstreamResponse->numberModification();

    if($downstreamResponse->numberSuccess() == 0 ){
        return $this->errorResponse("unable to send notificaton to all",401);
    }else {
        return $this->successResponse(['msg' => 'message send successfully','successfull' => $downstreamResponse->numberSuccess(),'failures' => $downstreamResponse->numberFailure()]);
    }
}
```

Just need  the opinion that is it possible to do it in this way and do let me know if there is any mistake or the changes that i have to make in my code. Waiting for the Positive response and Guidance

Comment: Yes you can send Push Notification to all users. You have to save Device Token (generated with FCM pluign) with email. and you can target them with that device token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You **can't** send notifications using their email addresses.

You should save in your Database the fcm_token of every user who registers. I suggest using the following package and reading the docs in it: [Laravel-FCM](https://github.com/brozot/Laravel-FCM)

You should also take care of refreshing the token if the device request so.